# What best practices to work with mongoDB? when to use

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I am studying node.js, and in most of the courses the staff uses mongoDB, I really enjoyed working with it, very simple and practical, but I have some doubts:

Nowadays, do most of the hosting already support MongoDB?

How to know if the project is not suitable for using MongoDB?

If not, which alternative to use with node.js? MySQL would be an option?

Thank you!